# How can i make a task for each item in the listBox if i select more then one item?

Tags: c#

First this is the listBox selected index changed event:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                label4.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string startTag = "Url: ";
                string endTag = " ---";
                int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
                int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
                int index = 0;
                index = label4.Text.IndexOf(startTag, index);
                int start = index + startTagWidth;
                index = label4.Text.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
                string g = label4.Text.Substring(start, index - start);
                label4.Text = g;
                mainUrl = g;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If it will help anything to see more clearly the dowork and button1 codes then this is a link to my project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/97h0j40f1oljhbb/GatherLinks.rar

Comment: It would definitely help if you *reduce* the amount of data/code, not increase it. At the moment the question should go in "category" tl;dr (too long; didn't read). So, try to pin down the issue to a particular method rather than around 100 lines of the code :)

Comment: I'd recommend a *short* but complete example that reproduces the problem.  If you can't put some effort in to try and narrow down the problem before posting instead of posting nearly 200 lines of code, why would anyone else put any effort in?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding this method:

```
private string GetUrl(object obj)
        {
            string startTag = "Url: ";
            string endTag = " ---";
            int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
            int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
            int index = 0;
            index = obj.ToString().IndexOf(startTag, index);
            int start = index + startTagWidth;
            index = obj.ToString().IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
            string g = obj.ToString().Substring(start, index - start);
            mainUrl = g;
            return mainUrl;
        }
```

And using it in the DoWork event like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            object input = e.Argument;
            string f = GetUrl(input);
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label2.Text = "Website To Crawl: "; }));
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label4.Text = f; }));
            if (offlineOnline == true)
            {
                offlinecrawling(f, levelsToCrawl, e);
            }
            else
            {
                webCrawler(f, levelsToCrawl, e);
            }
        }
```